# Assets have old URL

Tags: assets, url, image

I've just changed my local development environment from using `.local` domains to `.localhost` (no more DNS trouble on MacOS, yay!).
So I set Crafts `siteUrl` to `.localhost`, and while Craft serves pages that link correctly, my images still point to the old URLs. How's that and what to do now?

Images are mostly served like this:

```
<picture class="site-logo">
  <source
    srcset="{{ branding.logo.first().url('small') }}"
    media="(min-width: 100px)"
  >
  <img src="{{ branding.logo.first().url('large') }}" alt="{{ siteName }}">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good lord, this is embarrassing. For some reason I had a static URL in the asset source configuration.

**EDIT:** To provide at least a little value to others finding this: If you configure your asset sources, make sure the not use full URLs in the URL field.
So, instead of `https://example.com/images/` use `/images`.